# How to determine if field exists in same table in another field in any other row

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I am having troubles finding out if I can even do this.  Basically, I have a csv file that looks like the following:

```
1111,804442232,1
1112,312908721,1
1113,A*2434,1
1114,A*512343128760987,1
1115,3512748,1
1116,1111,1
1117,1234,1
```

This is imported into a sqlite database in memory for manipulation.  I will be importing multiple files into this database after some manipulation.  Sqlite is allowing me to keep constraints on the tables and receive errors where needed without creating additional functions just to check each constraint while using arrays in python.  I want to do a few things but the first of which is to prepend field2 where all `field2` strings match an entry in `field1`.

For example, in the above data `field2` in entry 6 matches entry 1.  In this case I would like to prepend `field2` in entry 6 with `'555'`

If this is not possible I do believe I could make do using a regex and just do this on every row with 4 digits in `field2`... though... I have yet to successfully get REGEX working using python/sqlite as it always throws me an error.

I am working within Python using Sqlite3 to connect/manipulate my sqlite database.

EDIT: I am looking for a method to manipulate the resultant tables which reside in a sqlite database rather than manipulating just the csv data.  The data above is just a simple representation of what is contained in the files I am working with.  Would it be better to work with arrays containing the data from the csv files?  These files have 10,000+ entries and about 20-30 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do it in SQLite, how about this:

First, get the column names of the table by running the following and parsing the result

```
def get_columns(table_name, cursor):
    cursor.execute('pragma table_info(%s)' % table_name)
    return [row[1] for row in cursor]

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
columns = get_columns('test_table',conn.cursor())
```

For each of those columns, run the following update, that does your prepending

```
def prepend(column, reference, prefix, cursor):
    query = '''
        UPDATE %s
        SET %s = 'prefix' || %s
        WHERE %s IN (SELECT %s FROM %s)
    ''' % (table, column, column, column, reference, table)
    cursor.execute(query)

reference = 'field1'
[prepend('test_table', column, reference, '555', conn.cursor()) 
    for column in columns 
    if column != reference]
```

Note that this is expensive: O(n^2) for each column you want to do it for.

As per your edit and Nathan's answer, it might be better to simply work with python's builtin datastructures. You can always insert it into SQLite after.

10,000 entries is not really much so it might not matter in the end. It all depends on your reason for requiring it to be done in SQLite (which we don't have much visibility of).

Comment: Not sure how I missed what you had there.  The answer you gave is pretty much what I had come up with but a bit extra.  Not sure why I would do the first step to get columns though.  It was only a specific 2 columns I was checking which were known.

Comment: yeah I was thinking you needed to do it in 'any other field' as well as 'any other row'. feel free to ignore that part :)

Comment: or let me know and i'll edit my answer to remove all the other cruft.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use regex expressions to do this, just throw the contents from the first column into a `set` and then iterate through the rows and update the second field.

```
first_col_values = set(row[0] for row in rows)
for row in rows:
    if row[1] in first_col_values:
        row[1] = '555' + row[1]
```

Comment: Hmmm... will this work ok?  I brought the csv file into a sqlite database for manipulation.  My reasoning for this is I have multiple file types which need to be brought in and written out.  These are all csv files which have different arrangements of columns but all have the same type of data.  In my python program, I detect the type of file (which translates to a specific arrangement of columns) and then bring it into a sqlite database which has a common structure for manipulation.  Then I can write an output file to any type (arrangement).  These files do have 10,000+ entries each.

Comment: @Goblinlord, I don't understand your skepticism. Nothing you say in your comment explains why you don't think this will work. This is an O(n) solution -- the fastest possible, asymptotically.

Comment: Yes... it will... but I was looking for a solution to manipulate the sqlite database not the csv data.  Manipulating the csv data means for each type of file I need to manipulate the data differently because the columns are different.  I need the constraints to be in place at data import (constraints on certain columns for uniqueness and such) only once all the data is imported do I want to manipulate.  The field data needs to be unique prior to manipulation.  If I do this I have to write functions for checking uniqueness of multiple combinations of columns and deal with these.

Comment: @Goblinlord, I think the code above is just basic example code; the idea is that (using SQL) you'll extract `id`, `field1`, and `field2` for all rows, use the above approach to create a list of `id`s to update, and then update `field2` where `id` is in `id_list`.

Answer (score 1):

So... I found the answer to my own question after a ridiculous amount of my own searching and trial and error.  My unfamiliarity with SQL had me stumped as I was trying all kinds of crazy things.  In the end... this was the simple type of solution I was looking for:

```
prefix="555"
cur.execute("UPDATE table SET field2 = %s || field2 WHERE field2 IN (SELECT field1 FROM table)"% (prefix))
```

I kept the small amount of python in there but what I was looking for was the SQL statement.  Not sure why nobody else came up with something that simple =/.  Unsatisfied with the answers so far, I had been searching far and wide for this simple line >_<.